# SonarQube, Maven, Jacoco - Code coverage showing as 100% but no file level details

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan, jacoco-maven-plugin

- Sonar 4.5.6
- Maven3.3.9
- Jacoco 0.7.7.201606060606
- Jenkins

Using the above combination, I'm able to

- successfully build my project
- all unit tests pass
- jacoco is creating the `/target/jacoco.exec` file
- sonarQube is displaying the unit test coverage as 100%

However, the issue I'm having is, the file-level coverage is not shown in SonarQube.

When I run the analysis using the SonarQube in my local box, I get the coverage result like in Figure 1 below.

[image: Figure 1: Results from local SonarQube]

However, when the remote Jenkins build runs, it displays only this part shown in Figure 2.

[image: Figure 2: Results from remote SonarQube]

I use the same command `mvn clean deploy sonar:sonar` in both places but the results are different. What am I missing here?

**Update**:

This is what I see when I open `target/site/jacoco/index.html`. So, looks like Jacoco is generating all the information needed. Sonar is not able to recognize it.[image: Jacoco report]

Adding the information found in the log. As mentioned in the comment, `target/jacoco.exec` and `target/sonar/jacoco-overall.exec` are found and is of size 15KB.

```
[INFO] [10:08:22.666] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 88 ms
[INFO] [10:08:22.666] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor...
[INFO] [10:08:22.675] Analysing /opt/sbs/.jenkins/jobs/CdnJwt/workspace/trunk/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [10:08:22.688] Analysing /opt/sbs/.jenkins/jobs/CdnJwt/workspace/trunk/target/sonar/jacoco-overall.exec
[INFO] [10:08:22.744] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] [10:08:22.744] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 78 ms
[INFO] [10:08:23.557] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [10:08:23.558] Analysing     /opt/sbs/.jenkins/jobs/CdnJwt/workspace/trunk/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [10:08:23.566] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] [10:08:23.566] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 9 ms
```

Comment: Pass the parameters "-e -X" to your build, so you have more information of what his happening and allows you to narrow down what's going wrong.

Comment: did you move the class file output folder around? Or change its default location? The coverage will only show alle information if the coverage file and the class files are available / found during the sonar plugin execution

Comment: I enabled "-e -X" and got the debug information. I couldn't find anything suspicious in the first glance. 
@wemu, I verified 

* the class files are in `target/classes` as expected.
* `jacoco.exec` file is present under `target`
* Jacoco reports are under `target/site/jacoco`. I can open the `index.html` and see the file-level coverage details there.
* Under `target/sonar`, I see `jacoco-overall.exec`

Do you see anything that is odd here? This is exactly how I have it local sonar and it works, but in remote sonar, it only shows the high-level coverage %, not the file-level break down.

Comment: has the remote sonar server the same plugins running? e.g. does it know about java? or did someone disable that / reconfigure that? It all looks good. If your local sonar works but the remote does not maybe comparing the sonar server configuration would be good.